# How to use dot navigation in Jackson JsonNode

Tags: java, json, kotlin, jackson

I have the following code:

```
 private val parsed = ObjectMapper().readTree(vcap)
 parsed.get("spaces")?.firstOrNull()?.get("block1")?.asText()
```

I'd like to use dot notation for navigating (for readibility reasons). Something like:

```
 private val parsed = ObjectMapper().readTree(vcap)
 parsed.get("spaces[0].block1")?.asText()
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using [jackson](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) greater than `2.3` then you can simply use [JsonPointer](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonPointer.html?is-external=true) expression

```
parsed.at("/spaces/0/block1")?.asText()
```

Of if you wanna use dot navigation which is called json pathing you can use [Jayway JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)

```
ReadContext ctx = JsonPath.parse(vcap);
ctx.read("$.spaces[0].block1");
```